# How to visualize change over time of multiple items at once?

Tags: graphing-functions, data-analysis, visualization

I'm writing a recommendation system for a news website. At any point in time, there are between 50-100 articles that are candidates for recommendation based on the algorithm, etc.

What I'm trying to do is find a way to visualize what these candidate articles are, and how their rank in this list of candidates changes over time. After 48 hours of being published, and article is no longer a candidate, so a given article won't be around any longer than that.

I think it'd be useful to be able to see trends and patterns about how articles evolve in this list of candidates both at a daily level (or 48 hour window), as well as weekly and monthly.

## Question:

What is a good way to represent the change in rank among a given list of candidates visually, over time?

#### Sample data

```
// 10:00 a.m.
var candidates = [
   { id: 111, impressions: 567890, ctr: 0.23 },
   { id: 222, impressions: 56790, ctr: 0.16 },
   { id: 333, impressions: 5790, ctr: 0.15 },
];

// 10:15 a.m.
var candidates = [
   { id: 111, impressions: 678901, ctr: 0.23 },
   { id: 222, impressions: 57890, ctr: 0.16 },
   { id: 555, impressions: 9876543, ctr: 0.08 },
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not terribly sophisticated, but something like the following may be a nice visual aid when comparing the change of any two candidates:
https://public.tableau.com/s/sites/default/files/rank11.png

Comment: That looks pretty good. Does that chart have a proper name?

Comment: I think it's just called a rank-chart. Here's a good link for plotting them in Excel: https://moz.com/blog/how-to-make-awesome-ranking-charts